# Confusions regarding porous pot experiment

Tags: experimental-chemistry

So, I have  studied  about  the porous pot experiment.Although I did understand the concepts of water level falling and rising due to difference in RMMs and thus difference in rate of  diffusion, I  still have two questions left:

Suppose hydrogen is outside the porous pot (in the jar), and carbon dioxide is in the porous pot...

1. Is the water level in the manometer in general dependent on just the gas in  the porous pot(CO2) or the whole mix of gas in the jar (H2 and CO2)?
2. Does all of the H2 diffuse into the porous pot or is  some of it left? I thought diffusion is  just the movement of gas particles to make the whole system balanced in concentration, so shouldn't there be an even concentration  of H2 in and out of porous pot?